# Only list visible fields

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I can list all fields with

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
fieldlist = [f for f in lyr.fields()]
```

Are there any method to list only the fields which i checked in "Organize columns". Something like:

```
for f in fieldlist:
    if f.isVisible(): #AttributeError: 'QgsField' object has no attribute 'isVisible'
        print(f.name())
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`QgsAttributeTableConfig`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableConfig.html) class holds information on which columns are hidden.

To list all names of visible columns the following should work (see image attached):

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
cfg = layer.attributeTableConfig()
fields = layer.fields()

for col in cfg.columns():
    if col.hidden == False and col.type == QgsAttributeTableConfig.Field:
        print(col.name)
```

[image: list visible columns]